# How to properly define and call a method on a derived class in C# with an unknown type parameter

Tags: c#, abstract-class

I am trying to define a "Transformation" class that will be responsible for returning a simplified array object based on a complex type.  The class will accomplish this via a "transform" method that accepts the complex type.  This is based on Fractal (http://fractal.thephpleague.com/transformers/), but I am trying to implement something similar in C#.

So far, I have defined an abstract base `TransformerAbstract` class that contains some properties and methods common to every derived transformer class:

```
public abstract class TransformerAbstract
{
    public abstract object transform(object entity);
}
```

I am struggling with how to implement the `transform` method, because I need to know what the complex type is so I can create the transformation, which will be different for every derived transformation class (for example: `CycleTransformer`, etc.)

```
 public class CycleTransformer : TransformerAbstract
 {
    public override object transform(object entity)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I have several other places in my applicationwhere I want to be able to transform the data - for example, take the following snippet:

```
    protected object[] fireTransformer(TransformerAbstract transformer, object data)
    {
        var includedData = new object();

        var transformedData = transformer.transform(data);

        if (transformerHasIncludes(transformer))
        {
            includedData = fireIncludedTransformers(transformer, data);
            //serialize & merge includes
        }

        object[] returnData = new object[1];
        returnData[0] = transformedData;
        returnData[1] = includedData;

        return returnData;
    }
```

I appear to have two problems:

1. I can't mark the method as `abstract` because I need to know the entity type.
2. If I mark the method as `virtual` then the code always calls the base class instead of the derived one, even though I can see at run time via debugging that the correct instance of the class is generated.

I tried using generics early on (e.g. `TransformerAbstract<T> : ITransformer<T>`) but that forced me to supply a type constraint on any class that uses TransformerAbstract, which I thought was overly restrictive.

Comment: *I tried using generics early on (e.g. TransformerAbstract<T> : ITransformer<T>) but that forced me to supply a type constraint on any class that uses TransformerAbstract, which I thought was overly restrictive.* Why do you think this would be overly restrictive?

Comment: I have a few different classes that use the _TransformerAbstract_ class as a type for internal properties.  Maybe I am thinking about it the wrong way, but when I tried using generics I needed to define a type constraint that the defining class every time I wanted to use TransformerAbstract.

Comment: *I needed to define a type constraint that the defining class every time I wanted to use TransformerAbstract.* I don't really understand what you mean by this.  From what you asked, I'd assume that you'd be creating types like `BookTransform : TransformerAbstract<Book>` which knows how to transform books.  That should work fine, and shouldn't be too restrictive.

Comment: Also, it's a common pattern to have a non-generic implementation of the interface *just in case* you need to grab all types that implement `ITransformer<T>`.  Call it `ITransformer` and have a `Transform` method that takes and returns an object.  Similar pattern to IList<T> which still implements IList.

Comment: @Will - Interesting point about the non-generic interface - If I have the generic version implement that interface and then the abstract class implement that, wont all derived classes have to define two Transform methods, such as `Transform(object o)` and `Transform(Book book)` ?

Comment: Yep, that's how it goes.  Normally, your implementation of `Transform(object o)` simply casts the object to (in this case) type `Book` and returns the result of the generic implementation; this throws, of course, on the incorrect type.  If that isn't satisfactory, add a method `bool CanTransform(object o)` or `bool TryTransform(object input, out object output)` which can gracefully handle the transform tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably stop using object and instead use interfaces.

```
interface ITransformResult<T>
{

}

interface ITransformable<T>
{

}

interface ITransformInclude<T>
{

}

interface ITransformer<T>
{
    ITransformResult<T> Transform(ITransformable<T> data);
    bool HasIncludes { get; }

    IEnumerable<ITransformInclude<T>> FireIncludes(ITransformable<T> data);
}

class TransformedData<T>
{
    public ITransformResult<T> Result { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ITransformInclude<T>> Includes { get; set; }
}
```

Now that you have a strongly typed structure your function would be as simple as:

```
protected TransformedData<T> fireTransformer<T>(ITransformer<T> transformer,
                                                ITransformable<T> data)
{
    return new TransformedData<T>
    {
        Result = transformer.Transform(data),
        Includes = transformer.HasIncludes 
                   ? transformer.FireIncludes(data) 
                   : null
    };
}
```

Comment: Thank you - any chance you could provide an example of how you would call this function using a strongly typed class in place of ```<T> ```?

Comment: I tried creating a new class that implements ITransformer<T> (e.g. CycleTransformer : ITransformer<Cycle> { } ) but I'm not sure if this is what you intended. The Transform method of the class becomes ITransformResult<Cycle> Transform (ITransformable<Cycle> data) { } - but the "data" properties are still hidden. In addition, how do I return something of type ITransformResult<Cycle> ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this works for your case or not. You can try virtual and override keywords.

```
public abstract class TransformerAbstract
{
    public virtual object transform(object entity);
}

public class CycleTransformer : TransformerAbstract
 {
    public override object transform(object entity)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Have a look at below code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Test
{
    class A
    {
        public virtual void show()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Base Class!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    class B : A
    {
        public override void show()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Derived Class!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    class Polymorphism
    {
        public static void Main()
        {          
            A a2 = new B();
            a2.show(); // calls derived class.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this still calls the base class.

Comment: @user2710915 I made some edits to this post. I am not getting why virtual and override combination is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Would this do what you need?

```
    public class CycleTransformer : TransformerAbstract
    {
        public override object Transform(object entity)
        {
            if (entity is CycleData)
            {
                // Do transform
            }
            else if (entity is FireData)
            {
                // Do transform
            }
            else
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This would probably work but I'd have to write new if statements for every new transform.